# Wrong ENtry and Exits marked

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to mark high and low of third candle of day

Long Entry - if price breaks the marked high , risk to reward 2:1
Long Exit - if price reaches marked low

Short Entry - if price breaks down the marked low , risk to reward 2:1
Short Exit - if price reaches marked high

Exit all positions at 3 PM for the day

This does not seem to work in code as it is only taking long trades and also at wrong prices and stoploss

```
// © ajaymshr42

//@version=4
strategy("Intraday 15 min third candle")
high_third = 0
low_third = 0
target = 0
stoploss = 0

LongEntry=false
LongExit=false

ShortEntry=false
ShortExit=false

if time >= timestamp(2021,01,01,0,0,0)
    
    if hour(time) == 9 and minute(time) == 45
        high_third = high[0]
        low_thrid = low[0]
        
        
    // Entry after 10 AM and upto 1 PM 
    if hour(time) >= 10 and hour(time) < 13
        if close[0] > high_third and not(ShortEntry) and not(LongExit)
            LongEntry=true
            strategy.entry("Long",strategy.long,100,when=LongEntry)
            target = high[0] + 2*(high[0] - low[0])
            stoploss= low_third
        if close[0] > low_third and not(LongEntry) and not(ShortExit)
            ShortEnrty=true
            strategy.entry("Short",strategy.short,100,when=LongExit)
            target = low[0] - 2*(high[0] - low[0])
            stoploss = high_third
    
    // Exit on Target
    if hour(time) >= 10 and hour(time) < 15
        if close[0] >= target and LongEntry 
            LongExit=true
            strategy.close("Long",when=LongExit)
        if close[0] <= target and ShortEntry
            ShortExit=true
            strategy.close("Short",when=ShortExit)
    
            
    // Exit on StopLoss
    if hour(time) >= 10 and hour(time) < 15
        if close[0] <= stoploss and LongEntry 
            LongExit=true
            strategy.close("Long",when=LongExit)
        if close[0] >= stoploss and ShortEntry
            ShortExit=true
            strategy.close("Short",when=ShortExit)
            
    if hour(time) == 15 
        strategy.close_all()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are declaring stops and limits you need to use `var` in the declaration so the variables hold their values between bar updates, otherwise they will recalculate on each bar. example:

```
var target = 0.0
```

Additionally, when re-assigning variables later we can not use `=` again.

Variables are first defined with `=`, then re-assignment is done with `:=`. Using these two methods we can **"set and save"** our exit levels. Example:

```
if close[0] > low_third and not(LongEntry) and not(ShortExit)
    target := low - 2 * (high - low)
```

lastly, if we want to exit at those defined levels, we can use `strategy.exit()` and use the `limit` and `stop` arguments. `strategy.close()` will wait for the close of the bar, which can result in your levels being exceeded.

Cheers, and best of luck